# db_query unknown column on where clause?

Tags: database

I am getting this error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Weddings' in 'where clause': SELECT id from galleries_types WHERE name="Weddings"; Array ( ) in catering_gallery_add_image_submit() (line 195

Why does it think 'weddings' is a column? It clearly is `where name='Weddings'`. What's up with the blank array on the end?

This is the code I am using.

```
$a = db_query('SELECT id from galleries_types WHERE name="'.$form_state['values']['id'].'"');
```

Comment: This question is for Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 2):

If you're new to Drupal or PHP coding, you've created a nice example of how *not to write an sql query*. What you've written is open to SQL-Injection.

Please review the [Database API Examples Documentation page](https://www.drupal.org/node/310072).

A "correct" way to write this query using the API could look like (adapting 1 of the top examples to your code) the following.

```
$result = db_query("SELECT id from {galleries_types} WHERE name = :name", array(':name' => $form_state['values']['id']));
```

You will want to make use of placeholders in PDO to write your queries.

Comment: Hi @tenken I think your answer is right but you should not use additional check_plain() call, placeholder value will be sanitized by db_query().

Comment: ok thanks. I rarely use db queries off of form state like this and forgot the db layer is doing some sanitation itself.